# Use PDO query inside a PHP Function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am not a professional, just started learning PHP coding.

I am having some issues getting PDO to work inside a function. Hope someone will show me the correct way to code it inside a function.

```
function testKey($key){
// CHECK IF LINK IS AVAILABLE IN THE DATABASE
$result = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT _uniq_key FROM _link_key WHERE 
_uniq_key= :1 AND _active= :2");
    $result->bindParam(':1', $key);
    $result->bindParam(':2', $o);
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        if($rows > 0) {

            echo 'link is available';
            checkLink();

        }
        else 
        {

            echo 'link does not exist!';
        }
}
```

The PDO doesn't work correctly, and won't execute the PDO script.

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the problem? Please also post the output of your code.

Comment: If i remove the PDO outside of the function, the PDO works correctly and get the data from the database, if it is in the function, no data is present

Comment: If you didn't get the "undefined variable $o" message yet, then enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` atop your script. Next take a closer look at your function definition and its parameters.

Comment: did you pass the $key parameter while executing the function?

Comment: Found my error, added: global $key;

Comment: Perhaps you should post the dbConnect function. Perhaps there is some issue in there.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the purpose of function arguments

Answer (score 1):

```
function testKey($key){
    // global $key; BAD
    // Assuming that active must be 1
    $active = 1;
    // CHECK IF LINK IS AVAILABLE IN THE DATABASE
    // Assuming that dbConnect() makes the correct PDO object
    $result = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT _uniq_key FROM _link_key WHERE _uniq_key= :1 AND _active= :2");
    $result->bindParam(':1', $key);
    $result->bindParam(':2', $active); // only find active records
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    if( $rows !== false ) {
        // http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
        // If no record, this function will also return false.
        echo 'link is available';
        checkLink(); // not sure what this does
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'link does not exist!';
    }
}
```

Now call the function:

```
$mySpecialKey = 'mango';
testKey($mySpecialKey); // note parameter is passed here
```

Answer (score -2):

Found my error, working code:

```
function testKey($key){
global $key;
// CHECK IF LINK IS AVAILABLE IN THE DATABASE
$result = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT _uniq_key FROM _link_key WHERE 
_uniq_key= :1 AND _active= :2");
$result->bindParam(':1', $key);
$result->bindParam(':2', $o);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    if($rows > 0) {

        echo 'link is available';
        checkLink();

    }
    else 
    {

        echo 'link does not exist!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `$o` come from? For this to be a valid answer please explain what you learned so it will benefit others. Honestly makes no sense you don't pass an argument and use *global* keyword.  Alternately close your question.

Comment: This is a bad answer. Adding `global` to make it work means that passing it as a parameter is being ignored.

Comment: post your entire code. I think there are many things you don't understand and implement incorrectly. Someone will show you the correct way.

Answer (score -2):

little adjustment here

```
 if($rows > 0) {

    echo 'link is available';
    checkLink();

}
else 
{

    echo 'link does not exist!';
}
```

Try this

```
 if($result->rowCount() > 0) {

    echo 'link is available';
    checkLink();

}
else 
{

    echo 'link does not exist!';
}
```

Comment: How is this useful? What problem does this solve?

Comment: This isn't good advice. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php). `rowCount` doesn't do what you think it does.